# Connection Pooling Oracle ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis

I have an Asp.NET Web service which have around 20 to 30 methods to expose . For database I am using Oracle database with the help of Delete repeated wordNet and a single class for the DB Operation and for every request I open the connection and close once its job get done for sure , means that I am closing all the connection there is no connection leak in my code. I have checked this like 10 times but as I go and check in the database (Oracle 11G) there are many session are inactive more than 20 hours . I am looking these sessions in V$Session table but I am very confused how they are not getting destroyed after long time even I am closing all the connections .

Please share your answers with me because all I can do close all the connection and that I am doing very well but still there are many inactive session more than 20 hours . How is this possible ?

TNS.ORA

XXX=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=X.X.X.X)
      (PORT=XXXX)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=shared)
      (SERVICE_NAME=XXXX)
    )
  )

My Connection String Get class which will give connection string like 
"User ID=XXXXXX;Data Source=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX"

```
public class StaticConnectionStringClass
{

    public static readonly string connectionString;
    private static readonly string ConnectionSourceWebService;

    static StaticConnectionStringClass()
    {
        string ConnectionStringType = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringType"]);
        ConnectionSourceWebService = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionSourceWebService"]);
        try
        {
            if (ConnectionSourceWebService == "Y")
            {
                ConnectionStringWS objConnectionStringWS = new ConnectionStringWS();
                connectionString = objConnectionStringWS.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringType);
                objConnectionStringWS.Dispose();
                objConnectionStringWS = null;
            }
            else
            {
                connectionString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        finally
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                connectionString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My DBHelper Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data;

public class OracleHelper
{
    private string strConnectionString;
    private OracleConnection oConnection;
    public OracleCommand oCommand;
    private int iTimeOut = 60;

    public enum ExpectedType
    {
        StringType = 0,
        NumberType = 1,
        DateType = 2,
        BooleanType = 3,
        ImageType = 4
    }

    public OracleHelper()
    {
        try
        {

            strConnectionString = StaticConnectionStringClass.connectionString;

            oConnection = new OracleConnection(strConnectionString);
            oCommand = new OracleCommand();
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error initializing OracleHelper class." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public OracleHelper(string MyConnectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            strConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
            oConnection = new OracleConnection(strConnectionString);
            oCommand   = new OracleCommand();
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error initializing OracleHelper class." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            //Dispose off connection object
            if (oConnection != null)
            {
                if (oConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    oConnection.Close();
                }
                oConnection.Dispose();
            }

            //Clean Up Command Object
            if (oCommand != null)
            {
                oCommand.Dispose();

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error disposing OracleHelper class." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (oConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) oConnection.Close();
    }

    public int GetExecuteScalarByCommand(string Command)
    {

        object identity = 0;
        try
        {
            oCommand.CommandText = Command;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            oConnection.Open();

            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
            identity = oCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(identity);
    }

    public void GetExecuteNonQueryByCommand(string Command)
    {
        try
        {
            oCommand.CommandText = Command;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            oConnection.Open();

            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
            oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    public void GetExecuteNonQueryBySQL(string strSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            oCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            oConnection.Open();

            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
            oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    public DataSet GetDatasetByCommand(string Command)
    {
        try
        {
            oCommand.CommandText = Command;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oConnection.Open();
            OracleDataAdapter adpt = new OracleDataAdapter(oCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    public DataSet GetDatasetBySQL(string strSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            oCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            oConnection.Open();

            OracleDataAdapter Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, oConnection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }

    }


    public OracleDataReader GetReaderBySQL(string strSQL)
    {
        oConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(strSQL, oConnection);
            return myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    public OracleDataReader GetReaderByCmd(string Command)
    {
        OracleDataReader objOracleDataReader = null;
        try
        {
            oCommand.CommandText = Command;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;

            oConnection.Open();
            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;

            objOracleDataReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
            return objOracleDataReader;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void AddParameterToSQLCommand(string ParameterName, OracleType ParameterType)
    {
        try
        {
            oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(ParameterName, ParameterType));
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
     }

    public void AddParameterToSQLCommand(string ParameterName, string value ,OracleType ParameterType, int ParameterSize, ParameterDirection parameterDirection)
    {
        try
        {
            // oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(ParameterName, ParameterType, ParameterSize, parameterDirection));

            oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter 
            {
                Direction = parameterDirection,
                ParameterName = ParameterName,
                Size = ParameterSize,
                OracleType = ParameterType,
                Value = value
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void SetSQLCommandParameterValue(string ParameterName, object Value)
    {
        try
        {
            oCommand.Parameters[ParameterName].Value = Value;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

My ASp.Net Webservice Method

```
  [WebMethod]
    public TestList Test(string id)
    {
        string Message = string.Empty;
        TestList objTestList  = new TestList();
        OracleHelper dbHelper =null;

        try
        {
            dbHelper = new OracleHelper();
            dbHelper.AddParameterToSQLCommand("PI_1", id, OracleType.VarChar, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbHelper.AddParameterToSQLCommand("PO_CURSOR", string.Empty, OracleType.Cursor, 2000, ParameterDirection.Output);
            dbHelper.AddParameterToSQLCommand("PO_2", string.Empty, OracleType.VarChar, 2000, ParameterDirection.Output);

            DataSet ds = dbHelper.GetDatasetByCommand("Oracle_LOCAL_PROCEDURE_NAME");
            Message = Convert.ToString(dbHelper.oCommand.Parameters["PO_MESSAGE"].Value);
            objTestList  .Message = Message;
            dbHelper.CloseConnection();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (dbHelper!=null)
            dbHelper.CloseConnection();
            objTestList  .Message = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbHelper != null)
            dbHelper.Dispose();
        }
        return objTestList  ;
    }
```

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the connection pooling and enlisting of transaction commands in your connection strings - try adding `enlist=false;pooling=false`  I am not sure what the defaults are, but I always prefer to know exactly what I am doing...

Comment: Hi Dom Cotton, means i have to disabled the connection pooling .

Comment: If you are using connection pooling, then configure the parameters accordingly = `Pool Size=10;
Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;`

Comment: Hi Dom i also tried this one also but in that case some property like connection time out is not there with oracle connection class because we are using System.Data.OracleClient which do not have the connection time out property and DecrPool Size as well . I thing these properties will be in ODP.net oracle client.